# Why doesn't auto-complete work in ruby-mode?

Tags: completion, debugging, auto-complete-mode, ruby-mode

I have spent several days trying to debug `auto-complete`, it is working properly in Elisp mode, but when I go in Ruby mode it stops working. `auto-complete-mode` runs successfully, but the menu of candidates does not appear when I type the word or invoke the command `auto-complete`.

I installed `auto-complete` using `package.el` from [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/). I have not added any settings to my `.emacs` file.

What should I do to identify the bug?

I'm using Emacs 24.3.

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Is it turned off, or just not functioning? Can you start it with `M-x auto-complete-mode`? If yes, you can add hook for ruby-mode: (add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook #'auto-complete-mode) Warning: the code above is untested.

Comment: can you edit your question with your .emacs file.